# How to Get password_reset data from token?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, reset-password

I am working on **password reset functionality**.

As of now, the email field is mandatory to fill. But I want to remove that email field(which I will get by using the token from the database and keep it in a hidden field in reset form) from the reset form.

As I can see password_resets table has those passwords reset request records along with `email`, `token` and `created_at` fields.

I am trying to decode the token which I will get from URL, to compare with a token which is saved in the database.

I tried,

```
//Hash::make
//$this->hasher->make
//Crypt::decrypt
//sha1
//md5
```

On the token I will get from url.

But still I am unable to get exact matching token to compare with token which exists in database table `password_resets`.

I had went through this [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18570). Which says ***Password reset tokens are now stored as bcrypt of sha256***. But I don't understand how do I decode that token.

Do anyone faces this problem?
Any idea?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You can't decrypt a hash since hashes aren't encryption. Hashes are used to make a unique 'fingerprint' of a piece of data. Hashes don't contain the full data and therefore there is no way you're able to reverse it.

But the password_resets table should contain the token if it has been issued. A simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM password_resets WHERE token = ?
```

should return the email adress.

Make sure there's data in that table to begin with.

Comment: I agree I can't decrypt that, but I can create one from the token I have. I need that algorithm to create ditto token string which is saved in database.